# How to create a dynamic URL fragment identifiers in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

It is possible to create a url in [Thymeleaf to an URL fragment identifier](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#url-fragment-identifiers):

```
<a th:href="@{/search#item-25(q=${query},all='true')}">
    more...
</a>
```

However i want to dynamically create the fragment identifier (such that I can link to `#item-n`), something like (not working code):

```
<a th:href="@{/search#item-${n}(q=${query},all='true')}">
    more...
</a>
```

How can this achieved with Thymeleaf?

Comment: how about @{${'/search#item-' + n}(q=${query},all='true')} ?

Comment: @MarekRaszewski ok, that was simpler than expected. Would you mind to convert that in an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@{${'/search#item-' + n}(q=${query},all='true')}
```